# Elasticsearch check if key exist in document

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have key "field1" in the document of Elasticsearch. With mapping the field is an object.
sometimes field does not exist, sometimes the field exists but is empty ([]),
sometimes the field has the correct value -

```
"field1": [
   {"key" : "value"},
   {"key" : "value1"}
]
```

Now I want to write a filter with script query but get this kind of error

```
"caused_by": {
     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason": "No field found for [field1] in mapping with types []"
   }
```

Even when I write a simpler query

```
if (doc.containsKey('field1')) {return true;} else {return false;}
```

but I have many documents which have the field. I think containsKey doesn't check the first level in a document but checks the full path.

Can somebody help me to check field1 exists in document or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "field1"
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the **exists query** document, if field as `null` or `[]`(your case), it will not be indexed and `exists` query will not return that document.

Comment: yes, I did it but not only existing I need. I need a more complex query. 
I need to do a filter with fields under field1. so want to get all documents which key = value1

Comment: @HovoBaghdasaryan that is possible, can you share an example so that I can provide a working query for you

Comment: {
  "collection_properties": [
    {
      "id": 5727275,
      "brand": [
        1051
      ],
      "product_category": [
        5818
      ],
      "generated_color": [
        123321
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4408758,
      "brand": [
        306
      ],
      "product_category": [
        5788
      ],
      "generated_color": [
        123318
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have this kind of document, want to find documents which "brand" in this structure = 1051. collection_properties is my field1 from the question.

Comment: @HovoBaghdasaryan, so you want just the first item in the list?

Comment: no. collection_properties is an object inside my document. I want to find all documents where "brand" inside collection_properties is for example 1051.

With painless I wrote a loop for it but get the error "No field found for [collection_properties] in mapping with types []"

Comment: do you have some ideas?